# Integer word problem

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory

From ROPES #2  “Fun with Integers”:

> You are given three integers whose sum is $16$. The product of these three numbers is $90$. Find the sum of the reciprocals of these three numbers. Please provide your sum as a fraction in simplified form.

Comment: There are only a few possibilities to try; $3,3,10$ works.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a Lagrange multipliers $$x+y+z=16$$$$xyz=90$$So we set $\nabla f = \lambda \nabla g$ which gives the following system of equations $$1=yz\lambda$$$$1=xz\lambda$$$$1=xy\lambda$$Then we can divide the first equation by the second to see that x=y and back subbing for both equations gives $$2y+z=16$$$$y^2z=90$$Then after subbing equation 2 into equation 1 we get this equation $$2y^3+90-16y^2$$By inspection we can see that y=3 is a root to this equation and thus x=3 as well and z=10. Now all that is left is to find the sum of the reciprocals $$\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{10} = \frac{23}{30}$$

Comment: This is true and all and does generalize well, but the machinery seems a bit advanced for someone at the OP's level. Nevertheless, good skill to know and so I give you a +1 good sir!

Answer (score 0):

List out all $(a,b,c)$ such that $a\times b \times c=90\space (a,b,c\in\Bbb Z)$. They are not many. Calculate $a+b+c$ in each case to find out the answer.

It turns out $10\times3\times3=90$ and $10+3+3=16$. So $10,3,3$ are the integers. Sum = $\frac{1}{10}+\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{3}=\frac{23}{30}$

Comment: To find them all you can eliminate some variables :

Answer (score 0):

Three numbers that add to make 16 and multiply to make $90$ are $3, 3$ and $10$.

$$3 + 3 + 10 = 16 $$

$$3\cdot3\cdot10 = 90$$

The reciprocal of these numbers are $1/3, 1/3, 1/10.$

Therefore the sum of the reciprocal of these numbers is

$$1/3 + 1/3 + 1/10 = 23/30$$

Answer (score 0):

We know that $a+b+c=16$ and $abc=90$. Easiest way will probably look at factors of $90$ here. We clearly have that $a,b,c$ are all less than $15$, which leaves (according to some quick code I wrote):
$$6\cdot5\cdot3\qquad9\cdot5\cdot2\\
10\cdot9\cdot1\qquad 10\cdot3\cdot3$$

Only $10+3+3=16$

In you really want a more algorithmic solution, the first step is going to be to find bounds. We know that each of $a,b,c$ must be less than $15$, and also that at least one must be greater than or equal to $\left\lceil (90)^{1/3}\right\rceil=5$, which we can further improve to a lower bound of $6$ by noting that $6+5+5=16$. Thus, we assume WLOG that $a\ge6$. We further note that $b+c\leq10$. With these conditions alone we can write a very fast program to solve this, with the potential to optimize more if necessary for harder problems